# Bind-key M-h in in tmux + Iterm2

Tags: tmux, iterm2, iterm

trying to bind `option+h` and `option+l` to navigate between windows

```
bind-key -n M-h previous-window
bind-key -n M-l next-window
```

If I understand correctly there is some problem in the way *Iterm2* sends these sequences, but I can't figure out how to fix it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

remembered that I solved this before on the old machine
Need configure in Iterm

[image]